# Is there any better way to write my jQuery Code?

Tags: javascript, jquery

I've written some JavaScript to display and subtly hide pieces of information on a staff page. Essentially, there are 3 emblems and 3 sets of description. If you hover over the design emblem, then it will show the design team's description and images, vice versa. Here is my code to do this:

```
$('.emblem img:first').hover(
            function() {
                $('.description:eq(1), .description:eq(2)').css({opacity : 0.2});
                $('.devStaff').css({opacity : 0.2});
            },
            function(){
                $('.description:eq(1), .description:eq(2)').css({opacity : 1});
                $('.devStaff').css({opacity : 1});
            }
        );

        $('.emblem img:eq(1)').hover(
            function() {
                $('.description:eq(0), .description:eq(2)').css({opacity : 0.2});
                $('.designStaff').css({opacity : 0.2});
            },
            function(){
                $('.description:eq(0), .description:eq(2)').css({opacity : 1});
                $('.designStaff').css({opacity : 1});
            }
        );

        $('.emblem img:eq(2)').hover(
            function() {
                $('.description:eq(0), .description:eq(1)').css({opacity : 0.2});
                $('.designStaff').css({opacity : 0.2});
            },
            function(){
                $('.description:eq(0), .description:eq(1)').css({opacity : 1});
                $('.designStaff').css({opacity : 1});
            }
        );
```

Now looking at this, I feel that there is definitely a better way to do this and I was wondering whether anyone would be able to offer some advice?

Comment: Based on your description it seems this could all be done with CSS. Not that using javascript to do it is wrong, it would just be far less code. If you build this in jsfiddle.net you may get some really good answers.

Comment: Look for the repeated code and for code that stays the same - extract what varies, template what stays the same and then inject the variables into the template.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Generally, you shouldn't repeat yourself (http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Don't_repeat_yourself),

Try calling a more general function, like this:

```
function fadeOut(eqNum1, eqNum2) {
    $('.description:eq('+eqNum1+'), .description:eq('+eqNum2+')').css({opacity : 0.2});
    $('.devStaff').css({opacity : 0.2});
}
 function fadeIn(eqNum1, eqNum2){
    $('.description:eq('+eqNum1+'), .description:eq('+eqNum2+')').css({opacity : 1});
    $('.devStaff').css({opacity : 1});
}

$('.emblem img:first').hover(fadeOut(1,2), fadeIn(1,2) );

$('.emblem img:eq(1)').hover(fadeOut(0,2),fadeIn(0,2));

$('.emblem img:eq(2)').hover(fadeOut(0,1),fadeIn(0,1));
```

Answer (score 1):

You can replace `:first`, `:eq(1)` and `:eq(2)` by `:lt(3)` :

```
    $('.emblem img:lt(3)').hover(
        function() {
            $('.description:lt(2)').css({opacity : 0.2});
            $('.designStaff').css({opacity : 0.2});
        },
        function(){
            $('.description:lt(2)').css({opacity : 1});
            $('.designStaff').css({opacity : 1});
        }
    );
```

Answer (score 0):

I follow these rules I bookmarked a while ago, I would defiantly at least follow the first, use an #id rather than .class as a minimum you do.

http://www.artzstudio.com/2009/04/jquery-performance-rules/